# ng-repeat filter on specific value not working

Tags: angularjs, filter, angularjs-ng-repeat

What I'm trying to do is very simple. I want to filter the data in my table by typing the filter value in an input field. I am trying to link the input field to a specific value in the table.

This is the code for my input fields:

```
 <div class="form-group col-xs-6">
   <label>Sales Rep</label>
   <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="search.salesrep">
</div>
```

And this is my ng-repeat:

```
<tbody ng-repeat="target in arrayTargets | filter:search">
  <td class="salesRepTable"> {{target.salesrep}}</td>
</tbody>
```

I hope you guys can help me, I do not know what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 3):

It should be:

```
<tbody>
   <td class="salesRepTable" ng-repeat="target in arrayTargets | filter:search.salesrep">{{target.salesrep}}</td>
</tbody>
```

Comment: I tried this, but it still doesn't work... My data (arrayTargets) I get out of an $http.get so maybe it has something to do with that.

Comment: You should post the controller too

Answer (score 2):

Your input box binds to `search.salesrep`, but your filter binds to `search` (which is a complex object). Try this: `filter:search.salesrep`

Also, you are putting the `ng-repeat` on `tbody`, which means you will have multiple `tbody` elements. You probably intend to generate multiple `td` elements, so put the `ng-repeat` on the `td` element

Comment: Nice answer #fikkatra. I agree.
One thing #Krist#of#Pauwels have done nicely, used object variable. So that loosely coupled abstraction will be followed on value's.

Comment: He uses the .salesrep to bind the input field to search.salesrep, this way it will not use the input to filter other fields from the table

Answer (score 0):

filter on `search.salesrep`:

```
target in arrayTargets | filter:search.salesrep
```